# dotnet publish errors not available at stderr

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am running the image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1` in an automated CICD pipeline to build my applicaiton. For testing purposes I created a Hello World application, called dotnet-test-app. In case of an error, I want to get a logfile that contains errors only and the pipeline should fail. I use the following commands:

```
dotnet publish tests/dotnet-test-app/dotnet-test-app.csproj -p:PublishSingleFile=true -r linux-musl-x64 -c Release -o .publish/dotnet-test-app -flp:logfile=.publish/dotnet-test-app.out.log 2> .publish/dotnet-test-app.error.log

if [[ -s ".publish/dotnet-test-app.error.log" ]]; then echo "dotnet-test-app.error.log is not empty" && exit 1; fi;
```

To test my code I have added an error to the application. On the console I get the correct error message. The dotnet-test-app.error.log remains empty. Is it not possible to use stderr with dotnet? How could I achieve a comparable functionality?